# How do i increment a variable in a loop for every 500th element in the loop?

Tags: loops, vb6

Lets say i have a loop:

```
for foo = 0 to ubound(bar)

     if foo = 500 then
         foobar = foobar +1
     end if

next foo
```

In reality bar can range anywhere from 1 to 152023 elements.

So by checking if `foo = 500` i only get foobar incremented once.

I feel this is extreme malpractice by checking every static 500 number like below:

```
for foo = 0 to ubound(bar)

     if foo = 500 then
         foobar = foobar +1
     elseif foo  = 1000 then
         foobar = foobar +1
     elseif foo = 1500 then
         foobar = foobar +1
         ' Et cetera.
     end if

next foo
```

The question is related to a function in our legacy systems which gets `Out of string space`- and `Out of memory` exceptions when passed the entire `bar` as an input parameter. So i thought i'd loop through the function with 500 elements each time instead of 12010230123 elements at once.

So basically.

How do i increment a variable in a loop for every 500th element in the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use modulo to determine if the value of foo is divisible by 500 and the increment the value of foobar.

if (foo mod 500) = 0 then ...

Comment: Like a glove. Thank you!

Comment: Be aware, this will also increment if foo = 0

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly you want to loop with steps of 500 ?

You can do that as follows :

```
For foo = 0 To UBound(bar) Step 500
  'do your thing
Next foo
```